# How can I stop Visual Studio from changing the indentation when I save my file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have the following lines in my C++ file in Visual Studio 2022:

```
IUnknownPtr m_spTagInterface;   // Pointer to the interface that contains this parameter's information
                                // (always nullptr for groups, assemblies and arrays
```

When I click the Save button, the second line is moved to the left edge:

```
IUnknownPtr m_spTagInterface;   // Pointer to the interface that contains this parameter's information
// (always nullptr for groups, assemblies and arrays
```

I thought this behavior was controlled by the Adaptive Formatting setting, but that's turned off.  How can I stop VS 2022 from moving my lines around?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/bringing-code-cleanup-on-save-to-visual-studio-2022-17-1-preview-2/#:~:text=How%20to%20enable%20Code%20Cleanup,Code%20Cleanup%20profile%20on%20Save%E2%80%9D.

Comment: Thanks.  That interesting.  However, I have no fixers enabled, so I don't think code cleanup can be my problem.

Comment: Also, in Options | Text Editor | Code Cleanup, the checkbox is unchecked.